# regex for http header in C

Tags: c, regex, string, http, header

I wanna extract strings from http header like: `GET http://www.example.com HTTP/1.1` using regex. I use this pattern: `^([A-Za-z]+)(\s+)(http?):\/\/(.*)(\s+)(HTTP\/)([0-9].[0-9])` and this works good and splits `GET`, `http://www.example.com` and `HTTP/1.1`. But when I use this pattern in C, it doesn't escape `/`(i.e, `\/\/` doesn't detect in C). How can I do this? or is there a better pattern for extract strings from http header?

Comment: You probably don't need any of those backslashes at all. Please clarify your question, and include a short example of *actual code* that illustrates the problem. You should also state which regex library you're using. We aren't mind readers, you know.

Comment: What is your exact regex string? `const char *str_regex = "([A-Za-z]*) *(http?://.*) *(HTTP/[0-9][.][0-9])"` seems to work well.

Comment: If I use `const char *str_regex = "^([A-Za-z]+)(\\s+)(http?):\/\/(.*)(\\s+)(HTTP\/)([0-9].[0-9])"`, I get "GET", " ", "http", "www.example.com", " ", "HTTP/", "1.1", "ET http://www.example.com HTTP/1.1" captures. The `\/` can be replaced with `/`s, but the most important is to use `\\s`.

Comment: `GET http://www.example.com HTTP/1.1` - this is actually a request line (not an header).
HTTP header is a name followed by a colon ' : ', then by its value.
[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_message)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note you do not need to escape a forward slash in a C regex library since the `regcomp` does not support regex delimiters.

All you need is to properly initialize the `regmatch_t`, `size_t` variables, use double escapes with the `\s` shorthand character class, and pass the `REG_EXTENDED` flag to the regex compiler.

I also suggest reducing the pattern to just 3 capture groups:

```
const char *str_regex = "([A-Za-z]+) +(http?://.*) +(HTTP/[0-9][.][0-9])";
```

Note the dot is "escaped" by putting it into a bracket expression.

Full [C demo](https://ideone.com/sKVvxR) extracting `GET`, `http://www.example.com` and `HTTP/1.1`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <regex.h>

int main (void)
{
  int match;
  int err;
  regex_t preg;
  regmatch_t pmatch[4]; // We have 3 capturing groups + the whole match group
  size_t nmatch = 4; // Same as above
  const char *str_request = "GET http://www.example.com HTTP/1.1";

  const char *str_regex = "([A-Za-z]+) +(http?://.*) +(HTTP/[0-9][.][0-9])";
  err = regcomp(&preg, str_regex, REG_EXTENDED);
  if (err == 0)
    {
      match = regexec(&preg, str_request, nmatch, pmatch, 0);
      nmatch = preg.re_nsub;
      regfree(&preg);
      if (match == 0)
        {
          printf("\"%.*s\"\n", pmatch[1].rm_eo - pmatch[1].rm_so, &str_request[pmatch[1].rm_so]);
          printf("\"%.*s\"\n", pmatch[2].rm_eo - pmatch[2].rm_so, &str_request[pmatch[2].rm_so]);
          printf("\"%.*s\"\n", pmatch[3].rm_eo - pmatch[3].rm_so, &str_request[pmatch[3].rm_so]);
        }
      else if (match == REG_NOMATCH)
        {
          printf("unmatch\n");
        }
    }
  return 0;
 }
```